# Display posts in an accordion - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, accordion

I would like to display my posts in an accordion on a single page in wordpress. Not some content inside a post, but the post itself with the title as the heading and the post's content inside the collapsible part. What would be the best way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: single page is generally used to show single post. you have to use sidebar for that

Answer (score 0):

you can use the accordion functionality wordpress default functionality only need to add the accordion jquery in your header.php file and css for that then activation code like

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-accordion'); ?>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no objections for using [jQuery accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion), then 
display the posts acc. to the accordion's markup and load the js. This should do the work.
Something like this:

```
<div id="accordion">
<?php while(has_posts()) { ?>
  <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    </p>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

(I cannot check this right now, so please verify the syntax.)